# jQuery Remove/Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, removeclass

```
test 123<br>
    test <span class="underline" id="1" onclick="test1(this);">hez
    <ul class="spellCheck_suggest">
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);">heyerdahl</li>
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);">heywood</li>
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);">hezekiah</li>
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);">hf</li>
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);">hg</li>
        <li data-wordid="1" onclick="test(this);"><font color="red">hez</font></li>
    </ul>
    </span>
```

Above is the HTML i have within one of my DIV tags.

Currently i do the follwoing code which works fine...

```
$(".spellCheck_suggest").remove();
 var mainContentHTML = $("#" + mainContent).html();
```

Which removes all .spellCheck_suggest classes from my dom, then gives me the html code of the above html which should only be:

```
test 123<br>
test <span class="underline" id="1" onclick="test1(this);">hez</span>
```

But the weird issue is if i try to clone

```
 var divclone= $("#divid").clone();
```

and then try and do either..

```
divclone.replaceWith(".spellCheck_suggest","");
divclone.remove(".spellCheck_suggest");
```

It doesnt remove it... My plan is to remove it then return the .html() to the user

Im i using clone or remove wrong?

Comment: What exactly does'nt work. Are you expecting the element to dissappear from the DOM when working with the clone? If so that is the expected behavior and one of the reasons for cloning an element, so as to work on it whitout changing the actual element in the DOM.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) with this issue? It's hard to see what's worng there.

Comment: I dont want it to remove dom just the clone, and yes will do that the now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".spellCheck_suggest", divclone).remove();
```

Comment: Me also thinks putting an entire unordered list inside a span tag looks weird, but that's off topic.

Comment: Long story its a custom spell checker

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you clone element, and then work with it, not with visible one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
divclone.find('.spellCheck_suggest').remove()
```